# Error: Package: php-intl-7.3.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64

Tags: php, centos7, iredmail

Hello there I am getting the following error:

"**Error: Package: php-intl-7.3.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64**" after I've completed all the set-up steps for iRedMail installation on CentOS 7.

```
Error: Package: php-intl-7.3.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
           Requires: libicuio.so.65()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-mbstring-7.3.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
           Requires: libonig.so.105()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-intl-7.3.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
           Requires: libicudata.so.65()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-intl-7.3.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
           Requires: libicuuc.so.65()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-intl-7.3.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
           Requires: libicui18n.so.65()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
<< ERROR >> Installation failed, please check the terminal output.
<< ERROR >> If you're not sure what the problem is, try to get help in iRedMail
<< ERROR >> forum: https://forum.iredmail.org/
[root@mail iRedMail-1.4.0]# php -v
PHP 7.3.28 (cli) (built: Apr 27 2021 13:57:06) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.28, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.28, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

**I have previously installed PHP 7.3** using the following guide https://linuxize.com/post/install-php-7-on-centos-7/

Can you guys tell me what the problem could be? I can provide any additional details.

Comment: Have you tried **reading** the error message? It gives a hint about where to ask support questions for that tool. Also, is this in any way related to programming?

Answer (score 1):

For a proper installation, please follow the **official** instructions from the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

The full yum output is missing in your question, but looks like the  **remi-safe**  repository which provides common dependencies for all PHP versions is not enabled (should be by default when you install the **remi-release** package)